# Magento 2 and Cloudfront as Full Page Cache

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, aws, cloudfront-cdn

I am using Magento 2.3.6 and I am currently in the research phase to use something interchangeably with Varnish as a Full Page Cache. Due to the fact that we use the AWS architecture, we are considering the possibility of using Cloudfront for this purpose (Magento 2 <-> Cloudfront FPC)

The problem is that I am unable to find any reference, an example related to such integration. The only thing I can find is WordPress and Drupal, where such integration works. From DevOps, I was also assured that on their side they are able to prepare Cloudfront for caching entire websites.

Therefore, I have a question for you.
Have you used or know this type of integration currently available on the market? Maybe there is some blog module or article that would help me shed some light on this topic. Is it even possible?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 supports [Built-in FPC and Varnish FPC](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/cache-full-page.html) only. Additionally, Magento cloud supports [Fastly](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/cdn/configure-fastly.html) FPC. We can use CloudFront as CDN in Magento 2 but not as FPC. My suggestion is you can use varnish as FPC with **CloudFront or Any** CDN.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Yes, I know that Varnish is in the Magento native stack. I am only researching the possibility of using Cloudfront as a full-page cache. Currently, we are using it as CDN for static files, but I was ensured by AWS DevOps, that there is an option to serve the whole page from Cloudfront instead of Varnish.
My main purpose is simply to find any examples of this kind integration (if there any)